# Object doesn't support property or method 'lazyload'

Tags: c#, jquery, lazy-loading

So I've been trying to implement jQuery's lazyload plug-in to help improve efficiency of the thousands of images I'm trying to load.

LazyLoad can be found here: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

However when I try to run their sample myself in my VS, I keep getting a Javascript Error...

***Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'lazyload'***

Javascript File:

```
$(function() {
      $("img").lazyload({
          effect : "fadeIn"
          /*
          ,appear : function(elements_left, settings) {
              console.log("appear");
              console.log(elements_left);
              //console.log(this, elements_left, settings);
          },
          load : function(elements_left, settings) {
              console.log("load");
              console.log(elements_left);
              //console.log(this, elements_left, settings);
          }
          */
      });
  });
```

HTML File:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload/master/jquery.lazyload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

               <div id="container" style="width: 765px; overflow: scroll;">
                    <img border="0" alt="Update/Edit Photo" data-original="/Images/editUptdatePhoto.png" src="/Images/editUptdatePhoto.png" width="100%" />
                    <img border="0" alt="Update/Edit Photo" data-original="/Images/editUptdatePhoto.png" src="/Images/editUptdatePhoto.png" width="100%" />
                    <img border="0" alt="Update/Edit Photo" data-original="/Images/editUptdatePhoto.png" src="/Images/editUptdatePhoto.png" width="100%" />
                    <img border="0" alt="Update/Edit Photo" data-original="/Images/editUptdatePhoto.png" src="/Images/editUptdatePhoto.png" width="100%" />
                    <img border="0" alt="Update/Edit Photo" data-original="/Images/editUptdatePhoto.png" src="/Images/editUptdatePhoto.png" width="100%" />
                    <img border="0" alt="Update/Edit Photo" data-original="/Images/editUptdatePhoto.png" src="/Images/editUptdatePhoto.png" width="100%" />
                    <img border="0" alt="Update/Edit Photo" data-original="/Images/editUptdatePhoto.png" src="/Images/editUptdatePhoto.png" width="100%" />
                    <img border="0" alt="Update/Edit Photo" data-original="/Images/editUptdatePhoto.png" src="/Images/editUptdatePhoto.png" width="100%" />
                    <img border="0" alt="Update/Edit Photo" data-original="/Images/editUptdatePhoto.png" src="/Images/editUptdatePhoto.png" width="100%" />
                    <img border="0" alt="Update/Edit Photo" data-original="/Images/editUptdatePhoto.png" src="/Images/editUptdatePhoto.png" width="100%" />
                    <img border="0" alt="Update/Edit Photo" data-original="/Images/editUptdatePhoto.png" src="/Images/editUptdatePhoto.png" width="100%" />
                    <img border="0" alt="Update/Edit Photo" data-original="/Images/editUptdatePhoto.png" src="/Images/editUptdatePhoto.png" width="100%" />
               </div>
```

So my big question is why am I keep getting this weird error? I've searched and browsed the entire internet for solutions. One answer that I found is that lazyloading is simply not supported anymore, however how can this be, when jQuery themselves keep updating their lazyLoading plug-in. 2012, they updated it to v1.8. Their sample websites work here:  http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled_fadein.html .... but when run on my own computer it doesn't work. I'm running in Internet Explorer (Internet says lazyload works on IE).

Hope some guru can answer soon. Thanks in advance!

More in depth Code for context...

HTML:

```
    window.onload = function () {//I tried putting lazyload here same error occurs};

$(document).ready(function () {
    //I tried putting lazyload here same error occurs
});

$(function() {
      $("img").lazyload({
          effect : "fadeIn"
          /*
          ,appear : function(elements_left, settings) {
              console.log("appear");
              console.log(elements_left);
              //console.log(this, elements_left, settings);
          },
          load : function(elements_left, settings) {
              console.log("load");
              console.log(elements_left);
              //console.log(this, elements_left, settings);
          }
          */
      });
  });
```

Comment: Are you importing the lazyload.js library into your project? after jQuery also?

Comment: Are you referencing the file in the first place.. Looks like that library is not loaded ??

Comment: Yes I am. Sorry I'll add it to the question.

Comment: have you tried it with jQuery version earlier than 1.8?

Comment: EVERY time something like this happened to me the library in question was not getting loaded. Somehow, EVERY time. Check your URL, make sure it is good. Check the timing of your function call to make sure the document is ready.

Comment: No I have not. Why would it work on previous versions of jQuery? It makes more sense to me to use the latest version 2012 lazyloader + latest version jQuery no? But I'll try it anyways to and i'll post results in a bit.

Comment: n8wrl : URL's are good definitely. document loading seems to be fine as well. I'll post more code for context.

Comment: Try loading it from somewhere other than GitHub, i've had issues with including from there before.

Comment: ^ First thing I've tried. Unfortunately didn't work. The github link works fine though.

Answer (score 0):

I think the implementation is not correct. I just implemented it and this work as a charm. Let me tell you step by step what I did.

1. I created a new website in VS 2010.
2. I have then added the DIV part that you have mentioned.
3. Added three pictures in the directory.
4. Added the CDN on the top of the MasterFile -- i.e., head part.
5. Then added the script

   $(function() {
         $("img").lazyload({
             effect : "fadeIn"
             /*
             ,appear : function(elements_left, settings) {
                 console.log("appear");
                 console.log(elements_left);
                 //console.log(this, elements_left, settings);
             },
             load : function(elements_left, settings) {
                 console.log("load");
                 console.log(elements_left);
                 //console.log(this, elements_left, settings);
             }
             */
         });
     });

Please check again and let me know..

Comment: Sorry but what is CDN stand for?

Comment: @charles.. CDN stands for Content Delivery Network.. The link that you place to get the jQuery instead of the actual jquery files are called CDN.

Comment: @praide....I have no idea why it's throwing me that error. I tried it again in Chrome. Didn't work either. I dont understand why its working for you, but not me.

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'lazyload'

Comment: In google chrome, it will not throw an error, but you cant see the images lazy loading.

Comment: I tried it with FF and Chrome.. FF -> lazyload and Fadein Chrome >> lazyload and Fadein

Comment: I try this when something weird happens.
1. Close VS and start again.
2. Clean the file and rebuild.
3. Startover again fresh

Comment: @Kevin B ... Wow, I figured out the problem....Kevin was right. Try loading it from somewhere other than GitHub, i've had issues with including from there before. I downloaded it and actually tried it. It worked like a charm. I don't understand how the link is perfectly working fine, but trying to reference to it as CDN doesn't work. So weird. Still learned a lot from these discussions. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

There is something disgustingly wrong with github's CDN. Link works perfectly, but trying to CDN to it will not get you anything. Instead you have to right click on the lick and Save as... to get the lazyLoader javascript files.